# Ubuntu server 14.04 after install, don't boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, grub2, bootloader

I installed `Ubuntu server 14.04` in an old PC. The installation process completed without any error. However, when it boot it stack in a blinking `-` and nothing happens.

I checked the boot priority in BIOS and the raid disk is first in line.

I tried and run Ubuntu 14.04 with live CD and run the following commands

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair    
$ sudo apt-get update    
$ sudo apt-get install boot-repair    
$ boot-repair
```

but the server don't boot.

Any idea, where the problem may be?

**EDIT**

Here is the output from the `boot repair` http://paste.ubuntu.com/24125024/

Comment: Forgive me if my question is silly, but which URL you mean? I just run the commands in the terminal, I didn't need any URL..

Comment: @yaylitzis When you launch the app Boot-Repair, it asks you to upload results to Pastebin, or keep it locally. If you choose yes, it should give you a result. Can you post this URL or if you didn't copy, can you do the process again and give the new results here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the raid configuration, I disconnected the one disc and I used only one hard disk.

I installed again the ubuntu server and the problem solved..